# error - karate.mapWithKey is not a function

Tags: karate

How do I handle below Karate error?

> javascript evaluation failed: karate.mapWithKey(list, 'name'), TypeError: karate.mapWithKey is not a function in  at line number 1

```
def list = [ 'Bob', 'Wild', 'Nyan' ]
def data = karate.mapWithKey(list, 'name')
match data == [{ name: 'Bob' }, { name: 'Wild' }, { name: 'Nyan' }]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably on an old version of Karate. Upgrade.

If you are still stuck, follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue